# How to monitor another app?

Tags: android

How to monitor another app behaviors in android like QualityTime in Google Play?

I try this by using UsageStatsManager with PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission.  But it returns nothing from

queryAndAggregateUsageStats(long beginTime, long endTime)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerodesktop.appdetox.qualitytime

APP monitor

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says on [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html):

"NOTE: This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application."

You are a third party app. So you won't get this permission granted on install. And you won't get any results unless the user goes to the settings application, and explicitly turns on this for your app.